# Recursive binary search and return index of object

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search

I'm having difficulty figuring out how I can return the index of an item in an array via the recursive binarySearch function I have below:

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> int binarySearch
      (AnyType[] a, AnyType x)
{
    int nMin = 0;
    int nMax = a.length - 1;
    int nMid = (nMin + nMax) / 2;

    int compare = a[nMid].compareTo(x);
    if(compare == 0)
        return 1;
    else if(compare == 1)
        return binarySearch(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length/2), x);
    else
        return binarySearch(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, a.length/2, nMax), x);
}
```

The requirement is to write a BS function with the function header and not to modify it. My function works fine, however, as I modify the array through each level of recursion, I lose the original index. We are also required to return the index of the item we're searching for. My implementation will always return 1.

Is it even possible to do this without creating another method and calling it from within the binarySearch function?

Comment: It's simply, the only non-recursive return you have retuns 1, which means that 1 is the only value the function could ever possibly return.

Comment: You need to do some arithmetic in your returns, there is currently no way for your programm to return anything but 1.

Comment: Actually, the professor just addressed this and told us we could just make a new function to handle the recursion and allow the one above to invoke it.

Comment: Great -- does that clarification solve your problem, then?  If so, please consider writing the answer and accepting it.  This is quite acceptable under SO guidelines.

Comment: I will, in 18 more hours when I'm allowed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after much confusion from pretty much the entire 300 student class, the teacher addressed this during lecture and explained that we could, in fact, create another function to handle anything we needed (position in this case).

So what I did was just write a normal recursive binary search implementation and call that from the function the professor required to have included.

```
public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> int binarySearch
      (AnyType[] a, AnyType x)
{
    return binarySearch(a, x, 0, a.length);
}

public static <AnyType extends Comparable<AnyType>> int binarySearch
      (AnyType[] a, AnyType x, int nMin, int nMax)
{
    if(nMin < nMax)
    {
        int nMid = nMin + (nMax - nMin) / 2;
        if(x.comapreTo(a[nMid]) == -1)
            return binarySearch(a, x, nMin, nMid);
        else if(x.compareTo(a[nMid]) == 1)
            return binarySearch(a, x, nMid+1, nMin);
        else
            return nMid;
    }
    rteurn -(nMin + 1);
}
```

Also, as a side note, I think my original question was poorly worded. I wasn't looking for a solution to the problem, I was more or less looking for confirmation in my thinking that the problem was impossible.

Answer (score -1):

Recursive search by *copying* the array on each recursion is bad for performance.

Pass the entire array on recursion, with additional range values, i.e. start/end indexes to process.

This is faster, and will also allow you to immediately know the actual index of the found element, since index values are unchanged.

---

**Update**

If the method signature cannot be changed, then a few changes are needed:

> ```
> int compare = a[nMid].compareTo(x);
> if(compare == 0)
>     return 1;
> ```

If the element at index `nMid` is equal, *that* is the index to return, not `1`.

> ```
> else if(compare == 1)
>     return binarySearch(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, 0, a.length/2), x);
> ```

[`compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) returns a "positive integer", not necessarily `1`, so test should be `compare > 0`.

Also, there is no need for the `else` part, since the `if` has unconditional `return`.

> ```
> else
>     return binarySearch(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, a.length/2, nMax), x);
> ```

First, the last argument of `copyOfRange()` is exclusive, so it needs to be `a.length`, not `nMax`.

Since the recursive call is passing in a range not starting at 0, any index value returned must be offset, i.e. `return binarySearch(...) + a.length/2`.

Again, no need for `else`.

*In addition* to all the above, if the value doesn't exist, the code will eventually fail because `copyOfRange()` will create an empty array, and code doesn't handle that, causing `a[nMid]` with a value of `0` to throw an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`. Need to add code to handle that.

Comment: Rats ... I realized during my meeting that I was incorrect in flagging this.  Can some moderator delete my flag, please?

Comment: As stated in the question, it's not possible to modify the function header. It can only take in an array and the object to search for.

Comment: @Prune Now that answer has been edited, you should be able to do it yourself.

Comment: Not that I've been able to find.  The help docs appear to say that I can't remove it short of a roll-back.

Comment: @Prune Oh sorry, I read your comment as "downvote", not "flag". Guess you are not a downvoter.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry it wasn't clear, but compareTo will only return -1, 0, or 1. I wrote the compareTo function myself.

Comment: @NathanBurgess Still better to use `>0`, so it'll work with any implementation of `compareTo`. Defensive coding against future errors.

Comment: Yeah, but this isn't something that's ever going to be used again, it was just a homework assignment. I wasn't worried about future-proofing it since it's now turned in and deleted from my drive.